# Wordlist Generator in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, word-list, bandit

I am trying to create a wordlist consisting of the same password followed by a 4-digit numeric pin. The pin goes through every possible combination of 10,000 variations. The desired output should be like this:

```
 UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 1111
 UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 1112
 UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 1113
```

and so on.

I created a shell script that almost get this, but awk doesn't seem to like having a variable passed through it, and seems to just print out every combination when called. This is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Creates 10,000 lines of the bandit24pass and every possible combination
# Of 4 digits pin

USER="UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ"

PASS=$( echo {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} | awk '{print $I}' )

for I in {1..10000};
do
        echo "$USER $PASS"
done
```

I though `$I` would translate to `$1` for the first run of the loop, and increment upwards through each iteration. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with `for i in {1000..11000}; do echo "$USER $i"; done`? If that's not a solution to your issue, than I think your description could use some clarification.

Answer (score 3):

> I though $I would translate to $1 for the first run of the loop, and increment upwards through each iteration.

No, command substitutions are expanded once; like, when you do `foo=$(echo)`, `foo` is an empty line, not a reference to `echo`.

This whole task could be achieved by a single call to printf btw.

```
printf 'UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ %s\n' {1111..9999}
```

Comment: Much better than a 10K element array. (even if you do feel somewhat sorry poor bash cranking out the brace expansions...)

Comment: @David fixed braces, I guess I was still sleeping while posting this

Answer (score 1):

Tyr this

```
$echo $user
UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ
$for i in {1000..9999}; do echo $user $i; done;
```

Comment: Oh duh I should have just used the loop to generate the pin, thank you.